# Return a json file of only the latest records per each foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and working through my first project. I have 2 tables a payments table and tenants table

payments Table => id, amount, rent_from, rent_to, created_at, updated_at , tenant_id

tenants table => .......

The tenants table has a one to many relationship with the payments table.

I need to return a json file of only the latest payments per each tenant_id.

The code

```
public function getPaymentsList(Request $request)
   {
$payments= DB::table("payments")
       ->where("tenant_id",$request->tenant_id)
       ->pluck("rent_to")

       ;

       return response()->json($payments);
    }
```

**Returns all the 'rent_to' records per tenant_id.

How can i return only the most recent  'rent_to' record for each tenant_id as json file?

Comment: Like orderBy `DB::table("payments")->orderBy("id", "DESC")->where("tenant_id",$request->tenant_id)->pluck("rent_to")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) instead of the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) for the full Laravel experience.  But you would probably want to set up a special relationship in your `Tenant` model to make things easier.

**Tenant.php**

```php
public function latestPayment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Payment::class)->latest();
}
```

Then you can use the relationship to obtain the results.

**YourController.php**

```php
public function getPaymentsList(Request $request)
{
    $payments = Tenant::with('latestPayment')->get()->pluck('latestPayment.rent_to','id');

    return response()->json($payments);
}

// "tenant_id": "rent_to"
//
// {
//    "101": "rent_to value...",
//    "102": "rent_to value...",
//    ...
// }
```

Comment: This works but i was finding out a way of filtering the latest records from the payments table.